# Destroy multiple text editing controllers at once on stateful class exit on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a scenario where I have to destroy multiple `TextEditingController()` at the time of `dispose()` life-cycle hook is called.

**StateFull Class**

```
class PersonalDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PersonalDetailsScreenState createState() => _PersonalDetailsScreenState();
}

class _PersonalDetailsScreenState extends State<PersonalDetailsScreen> {
 final spouseNameController = TextEditingController();
  final fullNameController = TextEditingController();
  final dobController = TextEditingController();
  final fatcaCountryController = TextEditingController();
  final taxIdController = TextEditingController();
  final nomineeNameController = TextEditingController();
  final nomineeDobController = TextEditingController();
  final fatherNameController = TextEditingController();
  final motherNameController = TextEditingController();
  final grossIncomeController = TextEditingController();
  final birthCountryController = TextEditingController();

  // ... 
  // Widget building and other functions in class
  // ...

  @override
  void dispose() {
    spouseNameController.dispose();
    fullNameController.dispose();
    dobController.dispose();
    fatcaCountryController.dispose();
    taxIdController.dispose();
    nomineeNameController.dispose();
    nomineeDobController.dispose();
    fatherNameController.dispose();
    motherNameController.dispose();
    grossIncomeController.dispose();
    birthCountryController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I thought it might be available in the `context` but couldn't found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use package:hooks_riverpod (https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod), you can create TextEditingController objects that "autoDispose" and can be created directly in the `build()` method, rather than having to be set up with `initState`. (You can even use them in StatelessWidget builds!)  It's quite useful, and there are other great things in that package as well.  It's from the author of Provider and RiverPod, two indispensable packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) your code could look like this:

```dart
class PersonalDetailsScreen extends HookWidget {
  const PersonalDetailsScreenState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final spouseNameController = useTextEditingController();
    final fullNameController = useTextEditingController();
    final dobController = useTextEditingController();
    final fatcaCountryController = useTextEditingController();
    final taxIdController = useTextEditingController();
    final nomineeNameController = useTextEditingController();
    final nomineeDobController = useTextEditingController();
    final fatherNameController = useTextEditingController();
    final motherNameController = useTextEditingController();
    final grossIncomeController = useTextEditingController();
    final birthCountryController = useTextEditingController();
    return Container();
  }
}
```

As Randal said, these controllers will automatically dispose on their own.

You could also use a map to clean up the build method a bit:

```dart
enum DataField {
  spouseName,
  fullName,
  dob,
  fatcaCountry,
  taxId,
  nomineeName,
  nomineeDob,
  fatherName,
  motherName,
  grossIncome,
  birthCountry,
}

class PersonalDetailsScreen extends HookWidget {
  const PersonalDetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controllerMap = Map.fromEntries(
      DataField.values.map(
        (field) => MapEntry(field, useTextEditingController()),
      ),
    );

    return TextField(controller: controllerMap[DataField.spouseName]);
  }
}
```